# Doing a cox regression, how do I analyze a continuous variable in which a lower result is worse?

Tags: regression, spss

I have this variable that is clinically worse the lower it is. Instead of interpreting, for example, a hazard ratio of 0.9 as "per unit increase in variable x, there is a x% reduction in risk for mortality", I want to get a >1 HR (for ex 1.05) and say "per unit **decrease** in variable x there is a 5% higher risk for mortality".

How do I handle this using SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple linear regression you have a dependent and independent variable, with an outcome model of:

```
y = - mx + c
```

If I understand your problem, `y` would be mortality, and `x` would be your clinical variable (i.e. when x increases y decreases). And it would be the same if you want to do your other example, because there is an inverse relationship between the two (i.e. when you decrease `x`, `y` increases).

It sounds like your hazard ratio is `m` (i.e. the relationship between the clinical variable and the mortality)

```
m = (y - c )/x
```

So to getting a HR>1 will depend on your data.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions otherwise please accept the answer